# Automatically made Google Sheet from csv data

Tags: perl, csv, google-sheets, google-docs

I am pulling data with a perl script, getting it in csv form, and I need to push that data straight into a Google Spreadsheet. My research so far has yielded Sheets to csv answers which is not what I need.

Comment: You probably need to do a bit more research then. Have you checked out the Spreadsheets API?

Answer (score 2):

A couple of options:

[Net::Google::Spreadsheets](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::Google::Spreadsheets) - A Perl module for using Google Spreadsheets API.

[Net::Google::Drive::Simple](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::Google::Drive::Simple) - Simple modification of Google Drive data

With the latter you'd write your csv file then upload it to Google drive.